# multiple field separator in awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying to process an input which has two field seperators `;` and `space`. I'm able to parse the input with one separator using:

```
echo "10.23;7.15;6.23" | awk -v OFMF="%0.2f" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $1,$2,$3}'
10.23;7.15;6.23
```

For an input with two seperators, I tried this and it doesn't parse both the seperators:

```
echo "10.23;7.15 6.23" | awk -v OFMF="%0.2f" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";" || " "} {print $1,$2,$3}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to set FS to a character list:

```
awk -F'[; ]' 'script' file
```

and the other builtin variable you're trying to set is named `OFMT`, not `OFMF`:

```
$ echo "10.23;7.15 6.23" | awk -F'[; ]' -v OFMT="%0.2f" '{print $1,$2,$3}'
10.23 7.15 6.23

$ echo "10.23;7.15 6.23" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[; ]"; OFS=";"; OFMT="%0.2f"} {print $1,$2,$3}'
10.23;7.15;6.23
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. And yes, it is `OFMT`. typo. How do I modify it to ignore a particular characters  `(` &`)` in the input

Comment: This should do the same: `-F';| '` as  `-F'[; ]`. comma or space vs group with one of comma or space.

Comment: Yes when you need to use a list of characters in an RE you can always write them as `a|b|c|d|e|f|g` instead of `[abcdefg]` if you feel that's useful.